# How to get images from FB to website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, app-secret

I'm working on publishing posts from our FB page on our website. Each new post and photos we added into our FB page I need to show in our website too.

I have this code, but don't working as I need.

```
require 'php-graph-sdk-5.x/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '...',
    'app_secret' => '{app-secret}', // don't know where to find app_secret for my page, I've found that just for apps, not pages
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'
]);

$access_token = '...'; // generated in developers, but with just for 12 hours, than this token is expired... :-(

try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->get('me?fields=id,name,feed,data', $access_token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

foreach ($graphNode as $node) {
    foreach ($node as $items) {
        print_r($items);

        // when access token was valid, I got posts from out FB page. But with no images, didn't find how to get add images to this feed...
    }
}
```

**So, my questions are:**

1. where I can find app-secret for FB page? I'm not able to connect to my FB page without that, I think
2. how to generate permanent access token, or if it's not possible, how to make i other way?
3. how to add images (new, shared, etc.) to my feed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no App Secret per Page, there is only the App Secret per App. You can find it in your App Settings.
2. Extended/Permanent Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ or http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ - for getting the feed entries of unrestricted Page, you can just use an App Access Token and you can hardcode it in your PHP code.
3. Getting images in the feed, not just messages: You need to specify which fields you want to get, or you will only get default ones. It is called "Declarative Fields": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog#v2_4 - also, check out the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post

Comment: 1. I have no app, just FB page. How to work with API without app_id? 3. I don't need to add photos to FB page, but from FB page to website. In my feed, in $graphNode there are no images, just messages (text part of our FB posts).

Comment: ad 2. in the link you gave me to extended tokend, there is: 'Enables your app to retrieve Page Access Tokens for the Pages and Apps that the person administrates.'... once again, I have NO APP, just PAGE. This link is probably for apps, not pages.

Comment: you need an app then ;) - without an app, there is no api access.

Comment: about feed results: please read about "declarative fields" in the docs, i will add a link to my answer

Comment: btw, you can´t just take the access token from the api explorer app. you MUST use your own app.

Comment: okay, I didn't know I need an app. A point for you :-) About declarative fields I know, now I have id,name,feed. Tried to add 'images', 'photos', whatever, nothing works. Is there any list of possible fields? Images I need to get from facebook are: images added to post directly, images added into gallery (dir 'web') and images which were shared (added into album and then share to the wall). Is it possible?

Comment: of course there is a list. you really need to start reading the docs, there is an api reference ;)  do some testing, the api explorer is perfect fot those kind of things.

Comment: for example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post

Comment: Dont worry, I read, but for me which see this API first time, there is many information and I've been doing it for last three days. Thanks for your answer and comments. Probably mark your answer by tick, is probably good, and will read next articles in docs. The last one sub-question, in codes (in  linked page the first PHP code) is $session variable. I tried to find it many times during these days, where is declared and I ccan read about this (is my personal session after login? Login where?)... Thanks for this last thing, then I will read and can mark your answer.

Comment: you do not need login to get the feed of a page, just the app access token. which is really just app id + pipe sign + app secret.

Comment: So, $session variable in PHP code snippet  developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post is "xxx|yyy", where "xxx" is app_id and "yyy" is "app_secret"? Where is it written, I'd like to study a little bit more about... You're great my friend! Really appreciate!

Comment: no, that´s not the session, that´s the access token...and yes, that´s an app access token. read the 2 links in number 2 of my answer, that´s where it is explained. i suggest starting without the php sdk first, and use php curl for the graph api. that way, you learn how it really works.